# General formula for calculating torsional and warping constants of built-up section

Tags: steel, building-design, eurocodes

In order to calculate the elastic critical moment of a laced double I-section, I need the torsional and warping constants. Is there a general formula to obtain this? BS 5950 only has formulas for single I-section. I tried Googling but it seems such information is not readily available.